# Hardware configuration required for DNS server

Tags: arch-linux, dns, dynamic-dns

How can I know Hardware configuration required for DNS server:

1. What will be the expected QPS (Queries Per Second) on the server.

> > 5/Sec and peak time 10-20/Sec
> >
> > How many hosts will be querying to the server.
> >     3-5?
> >
> > How many domains will be hosted on the server.
> >     10-15?

Comment: One would almost say you probably can't buy hardware incapable of that - the one that is too slow is too expensive (since it is already in a museum).

Comment: [This!](http://www.elesia.it/tr386.php) 512KB of awesomeness for Arch to run in >=) Although to be fair, once you got arch+dns running in that foot print it would probably still walk 20 requests a second in.

Answer (score 0):

As peterph noted, anything.

A [t2.micro EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#T2) would cover it and set you back about $110 USD a year (down to around $60 if you [reserve it](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/).